# Inherited variable undefined when inside of string?

Tags: python, string, class, inheritance, undefined

```
class dad():
    dadthing = "i like pandas"


class son(dad):
    print "dad and %s" % dadthing


x = son()
x
```

Similar to what im trying to do, when i run it through the child class it says dadthing is not defined, yet if i just call the variable like

```
print x.dadthing
```

it calls the variable just fine. whats up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are trying to use a print command in the body of your class. The body of a class is read just one time, when a class is loaded in memory.

From the class body you can't access to the parent class property like this:

```
print "dad and %s" % dadthing
```

because the variable **dadthing** does not really exist in the **child class scope**. That's why the interpreter tells you that the variable is not defined.

If you want to access the property of the parent class from that point, this would be the way:

```
print "dad and %s" % dad.dadthing #calling a class property
```

If you try this, without even instantiate the class, you will see that the variable is printed, because you're calling a class property, not an instance property.

```
class dad():
    dadthing = "i like pandas"


class son(dad):
    print dad.dadthing #calling a class property
```

You must call the instance property from the __init__ function. The __init__ method is the constructor. This method is called when the object is created completely.

```
class dad():
    dadthing = "i like pandas"


class son(dad):
   def __init__(self):
       print "dad and %s" % self.dadthing


x = son()
```

Comment: Here is a deeper explanation of what happens under the hood when a class is defined in Python http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/15/under-the-hood-of-python-class-definitions. Basically, the statements written just below the class declaration are executed before the class even exists.

Comment: You're right @javidcf. It would be more correct to say that the property of the parent class is not accessible from there.